# Kentico 9 - Data cache Macro

Tags: caching, macros, kentico

I'm doing the field validation on the custom table.
This is the macro on the validation field:

```js
{% 
 foreach (i IN CMSContext.Current.GlobalObjects.CustomTables["customtable"].Items.ItemsAsFields.IdNumber) 
 {
   if (i == IdNumber.Value){
    return false;
   } 
 }
  return true;
 #%}
```

The issue start from this part of the macro :
*CMSContext.Current.GlobalObjects.CustomTables["customtable"].Items.ItemsAsFields.IdNumber*

This line of macro should get all the data entered in my customtable, however it didn't get recent ones.
In this case my validation won't work and I will keep entering the same IdNumber.

This is the way how I found out, when I ran this macro via System - Macro - Benchmark :
{%CMSContext.Current.CMSContext.Current.CMSContext.Current.GlobalObjects.CustomTables["customtable"].Items.ItemsAsFields.ItemID #%}

I tested "Clear Cache", this worked. So it seems to me cache issue.
So I have turned off all of the cache in Setting - System - Performance:

- Server content caching
- Server file caching
- Client caching
- Output caching

and yet, that line of macro not returning the latest data when I entered new data.

Is there any way to clear cache using macro or other option to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the cause of your issue ([hotfix](https://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes) 9.0.46):

```
Custom tables - Custom table Items collection incorrectly cached in macros
When using the Items property of custom table objects in macros, the data was incorrectly cached. For example, when using the 'GlobalObjects.CustomTables["<customtablecodename>"].Items' macro, the latest data was not returned.
```

Comment: Could be, could be...I was searching for that bug but I couldn't find it...I guess there was a typo in my search phrase :)

Comment: Let me try this hotfix first.
Thanks Boris

Answer (score 0):

Neither the output nor the data cache is applied on macros (you can optionally manually [turn it on](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/macro-expressions/caching-the-results-of-macros) but it's off by default).

There is an extra level of caching which is not visible to the user - the API-level hashtables. Kentico takes care of updating the tables automatically whenever an object is changed via the API. So there are basically two options of what can go wrong:
- either there is a bug in the hashtables
- or you're not updating the custom table via the API but e.g. via a direct SQL query and the system is unaware of changes made to the database

The question is: Are you using a SQL query?

If you are, you have to flush the cache manually by calling [`ClearHashtables`](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/10_0/api/html/M_CMS_DataEngine_AbstractProvider_ClearHashtables_1.htm).

Comment: Thanks Rocky.
It uses CMS mechanism to save the data, that's what I can figured, didn't seem to use SQL query.
if I'd to use ClearHashTables manually, Is there any example how I can apply it to the macro?

Comment: You'd have to [register a custom macro method](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/macro-expressions/extending-the-macro-engine/registering-custom-macro-methods). Anyways, since you're using Kentico's API it seems like a bug and it's very likely it's been fixed by the 9.0.46 hotfix.